# Which sizer to use and how to implement? (wxPython Phoenix)

Tags: wxpython

I have 5 widgets that I need to lay out on the panel.

My desired layout is this:

```
StaticText:    TextCtrl
StaticText:    TextCtrl
         Button
```

I need the whole implementation. You get my upvote for the cleanest solution.

However, my attempt is a little hacky.

```
sizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(orient=wx.HORIZONTAL)
sizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(orient=wx.HORIZONTAL)
sizer3 = wx.BoxSizer(orient=wx.VERTICAL)

sizer1.Add(window=labelOfTextFieldForURL,
           border=5,
           flag=wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
sizer1.Add(window=self.textFieldForURL,
           border=5,
           flag=wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

sizer2.Add(window=labelOfTextFieldForSearchTerm,
           border=5,
           flag=wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
sizer2.Add(window=self.textFieldForSearchTerm,
           border=5,
           flag=wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

sizer3.AddStretchSpacer()
sizer3.Add(sizer=sizer1,
           border=5,
           flag=wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
sizer3.Add(sizer=sizer2,
           border=5,
           flag=wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
sizer3.Add(window=buttonCount,
           border=5,
           flag=wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
sizer3.AddStretchSpacer()

panel.SetSizer(sizer3)
panel.Layout()
```

Comment: what problems or errors are you encountering?

Comment: None, I just want a cleaner solution, probably by using FlexGridSizer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple app that gives a quick overview of how to achieve your layout. See code comments for an explanation

```
import wx

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title=wx.EmptyString, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                          size=wx.Size(500, 300), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

        # create a flex grid sizer with 3 rows and 2 columns, 0 gaps between rows and columns
        flex_grid_sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(3, 2, 0, 0)
        # make the TextCtrls expand
        flex_grid_sizer.AddGrowableCol(1)
        flex_grid_sizer.SetFlexibleDirection(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        flex_grid_sizer.SetNonFlexibleGrowMode(wx.FLEX_GROWMODE_ALL)

        # Start Row 1
        self.static_text_1 = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Static Text", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.static_text_1.Wrap(-1)
        flex_grid_sizer.Add(self.static_text_1, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5)

        self.textctrl_1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        flex_grid_sizer.Add(self.textctrl_1, 1,
                            wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        # Start Row 2
        self.stat_text_2 = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Static Text", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.stat_text_2.Wrap(-1)
        flex_grid_sizer.Add(self.stat_text_2, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5)

        self.textctrl_2 = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        flex_grid_sizer.Add(self.textctrl_2, 1,
                            wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        # Start Row 3
        # Add a spacer to center the bytton
        flex_grid_sizer.AddStretchSpacer()

        self.button = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "A Button", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        flex_grid_sizer.Add(self.button, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(flex_grid_sizer)
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre(wx.BOTH)


app = wx.App()
frame = TestFrame()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: This is too complicated.

Comment: this question is not well suited for stackoverflow, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, you would get a better reception here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/